# Map Dictionaries of IEnumerables to each other

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've got the following dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<A, IEnumerable<B>> dict1;
Dictionary<A, IEnumerable<C>> dict2;
Dictionary<C, IEnumerable<B>> dict3;
```

I want to have the subset that'd effectively be `Dictionary<A, Dictionary<C, IEnumerable<B>>>`. Is there an easy way to transform these dictionaries to the target?

I've considered making a new class `AC` so that the result could just be `Dictionary<AC, IEnumerable<B>>`, but I'm still not sure that gets me closer to what I want.

Comment: I could reasonably change `Dictionary<A, IEnumerable<C>>` to `Dictionary<A, HashSet<C>>`, but that makes this a different, perhaps less interesting, question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit more? Can you give us some more information? How does your target output relate to your input?

Comment: What is the key in your final dictionary? Is the `IEnumerable<B>` the same set of items as in `dict1`? Or of `dict3`? Or is it the 'intersection' between the two?

Comment: This was just a question I noticed given some data in a system that got me thinking this should be possible via set operations (intersect, union, etc). There's not necessarily a specific use case in mind (hence my last comment).

Comment: @Rob, it'd be the intersection of the two (e.g. IEnumerable<B> that'd be keyed by both A and C)

Comment: What about an item which is not in `dict3`? Where does it go (or is it not included at all)? How does `dict2` play into this - considering all the data to populate `IEnumerable<B>` is described in `dict1` and `dict2`. These kinds of questions are why it'd be good to have an example set of data and desired results in the question

Comment: I think I figured out what I was trying to do (see answer). I should've included `dict1` included all `B`, and `dict2` included all `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Dictionary<A, Dictionary<C, IEnumerable<B>>> composedDict =>
  dict2.ToDictionary(ac => ac.Key, ac => ac.Value.ToDictionary(c => c, c => dict3[c]));
```

Comment: Where does `dict1` tie in here?

Comment: Looks like I didn't need it (just extra data). It makes sense though, since `dict2` allows me to map to all potential keys that I want in `dict3`.